# How to share a specific folder on the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, shared-folders

I was wondering how to share a specific folder once someone on my network clicks on my computer. All that shows up on my computer is "Users" which would link to my username> Desktop> Folders I've shared. I want to skip that step where they have to click on username> Desktop.

I've google'd around and all I get are results about how I can right click a folder and hit "share with" certain people or everyone on the network. That's great, but they have to click on Users> Username> Desktop every time!

I run windows 7 home premium. I hope that isn't the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Share With dialogue, use these steps instead to create a new share with it's own name/path.

1. Right click the folder you wish to share and open the Properties Page, then click the Sharing tab.

   [image]
2. Click Advanced Sharing. Click "Share this folder". Give the share a name, and [edit the permissions](http://www.lockergnome.com/it/2012/05/01/advanced-sharing-windows/) to include anyone you wish to access the folder by clicking the Permissions button (the default is shared with Everyone).

   [image]
3. Save your changes, and anyone accessing it will be able to directly access it by it's name, rather than the full path.

   [image]

---

If you end up preferring this method, you can disable the Sharing Wizard (the one that was not working properly for you), by opening Folder Options (Tools > Folder Options from Windows Explorer) and unchecking "Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)".

Comment: This is it. Thanks for the hard work of doing the screenshots and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder and give it a name

Right click on the folder and click properties

Share it in sharing and security tabs.

In the sharing tab, click Advanced sharing, check Share this folder and under permissions  check all Allow boxes (if desired). OK. OK.

Click on security tab. Click edit. Click add. Type everyone. OK. Check all the boxes (if desired) with Everyone selected to give certain permissions. OK. Close.

You may also have other issues with FireWalls but this should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You could share the folder and set it up as a network drive on the others PC.

On your computer, right click on the folder you want to share and go to properties; Go to the sharing tab, and there is a button called "Advanced Sharing".... Click on that and name the folder as what you want to share it as. Click ok.

On the other's PC, go to Computer, and click on Map Network Drive (at the top of windows explorer.) Where it says Folder Name, type \My Computer\Folder (where My Computer is the name of your PC and folder is what you named the folder in advanced sharing. Click ok.

The folder will then appear as a network drive under Computer.

You can also take a look at this article... http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Share-files-with-someone